# header location not working when login

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, header, location

as you can see below i have a log-in page which will return to the index depending on the outcome. when i come to this page it just does nothing. the session's etc. register and login but i have to manually re enter the page my self?

```
<?php
session_start();

include("connect_db.php");

$tbl_name="users"; 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$pass=$_POST['pass']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

$username=$row['username']; 

$_SESSION['username']=$username;


header('location: index.php?login=yes');

}else {

header('location: index.php?login=no');

}

?>
```

Comment: [simple: `session_register` is deprecated.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) - [See for yourself...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and you're missing braces for `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` which the *"see for yourself"* would have caught.

Comment: `session_register()` => [Warning

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)

Comment: the session_register isn't actually doing anything for the form anyhow. thanks

Comment: so remove it from your question then

Comment: First things that jump out to me... You are open to SQL injections and your passwords might be stored in plain text which is a security flaw.

Comment: basic error checking, reveals all. You're not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<?php
session_start();

include("connect_db.php");

$tbl_name="users";
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $username=$row['username'];
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    }
    header('location: index.php?login=yes');
}
else {
    header('location: index.php?login=no');
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks but still the same just a blank screen, i did change the headers to text to see if theres any other issue but the text displays fine. Any more suggestions.

Comment: What is written in `include("connect_db.php");`

Comment: Update your `$conn = mysql_connect($dbservername, $dbusername, dbpassword); ` by `$conn = mysql_connect($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword);` then run.

Comment: Also replace `if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); }` to `if (!$conn) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }`

Comment: i cant see any difference

Comment: i see the $ missing that is just a typing error on here the connect_db runs fine already and gets the info i need

Comment: yes `$` was not there and so it was generating error

Comment: ive worked out if i add the code directly to this code from the connect_db.php it works, but when using the 'include' function it does not...any ideas

Comment: Is the path correct? `connect_db.php` is located in the same folder of main file?